# GoogleMap: IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding takeScreenshot is stuck

Tags: flutter

I have the following integration test for showing a GoogleMap. For some reason the `takeScreenshot` call just gets stuck and the test hangs indefinitely. I've tried all kinds of combinations of pump, pumpAndSettle, with various durations, but nothing seems to work. It's also frustrating that there are no progress logs or any kind of logs during `takeScreenshot`.

Does anyone know what could the issue here? Thank you.

```
void main() async {
  final IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding =
      IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets('stuck takeScreenshot test show map', (tester) async {
    app.main();

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    do {
      await tester.pump();
    } while (
        tester.widgetList(find.byType(GoogleMap)).isEmpty);

    await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 10));

    await binding.convertFlutterSurfaceToImage();

    await tester.pump();
 
    await binding.takeScreenshot('screenshot-1');
  });
}
```

By the way, if I have the test do only this, the screenshot gets taken successfully:

```
testWidgets('okay takeScreenshot test show map', (tester) async {
    app.main();

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    await binding.convertFlutterSurfaceToImage();

    await tester.pump();

    await binding.takeScreenshot('screenshot-1');
  });
```

It seems like when GoogleMap is rendered `takeScreenshot` gets stuck.